# What is the use of functions.php file in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, themes

I am new in wordpress and I develop my custom themes but i don't know why functions.php file used in theme development of wordpress.Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or more to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

In case you missed it, you should always check the WordPress codex -- http://codex.wordpress.org/ 
You can find pretty much everything you need there.
As for your question: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Functions_File